# Как в css узнать ширину с учетом скролбара?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Есть задать ширину `100vw`, то это будет значение без учета скроллбара.
А как узнать только реально свободную ширину?

**main**

```
@import "./sliding-panel-component/sliding-panel"

*
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

body
  background: #232323

.main-container
    width: 100vw
    height: 100vh
```

**sliding-panel**

```
@import "./panel-sliding-panel"

.sliding-panel
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
```

**panel-sliding-panel**

```
@import "facade"

.panel-sliding-panel
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

    background: $COLOR_PANEL
```

Comment: @Alex: добавил..

Comment: @Alex: а скролбар обязательно будет 10px? просто размеры реально значимы..

Comment: @Alex: а задать размер скролу сложно? И Ваш с "Вашей Прелестью" вариант не работает, на семь пикселей подвел. Вас предали :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30750/discussion-between-alex-and-shatal).